# value of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-k}$.

Tags: calculus, summation

I want to compute the value of  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-k}$.

First i try to check whether this series converges,

\begin{align}
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} k^{-k} = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} e^{-k \log(k)} =0
\end{align}
Thus i see that series converges.

But how do we know the exact value of this series?

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).